# C# - Print/write out/change a mutable list of objects, properties is in another class. (great answers)

Tags: c#, list

Long time reader, first time poster. I'm hoping this is not an duplicate but the similar ones I've seen are all for other languages or complicated, which I hope this isn't. There should be a simple solution to help all beginners like myself.

I'm trying to make a function to simply print out objects created by the user that are put in a list of another class.

My class for Employee objects:

```
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
ect...
```

I made a print function(if it can be used):

```
public void PrintEmployee()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nID:{0}\nFull Name: {1} {2}\nSocial Security Number: {3}\nWage: {4}\n", ID, FirstName, LastName, SocialNumber, HourWage);
}
```

Constructor // turned out to be **irrelevant** but can help someone else doing a similar project

```
    public Employee(int ID, string firstname, string lastname, string socialnumber, string hourwage)
    {
        ID = 0;
        FirstName = firstname;
        LastName = lastname;
        SocialNumber = socialnumber;
        HourWage = hourwage;
    }
```

Registry class, with list and creating the objects: // turned out to be **irrelevant** but can help someone else doing a similar project.

```
public List<Employee> Accounts { get; set; }

    public Registry()
    {
        Accounts = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public void CreateAccount()
    {
        var employee = new Employee(0, "", "", "", "");

        Console.Write("Enter first name <Name>: "); 
        employee.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter last name <Name>: ");
        employee.LastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter Social Security Number<YYMMDD-XXXX>: ");
        employee.SocialNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter wage <XXXkr/h>: ");
        employee.HourWage = Console.ReadLine();

        employee.ID = Accounts.Count + 1;

        Accounts.Add(employee);

    }
```

I want to have each Employee printed in my own format, but I started with trying to just have them printed in any way. After **creating an Registry object** in the main method and call the print function I get **ConsoleApplicationName.Method** in the console.
The function should be simple(we have just started learning)and I'm probably gonna be embarrassed but for the life of me I don't know how to make it work.

**I have tried** to put the Employee print method into Console.WriteLine but it complains about static/void, I changed all of the properties to static and/or created instances of them but that doesn't help. Would inheritance solve the problem?

I could get it to work by putting the list and the function inside the Employee class? I've been told that it's good practice to have classes and objects  divided after what they are, do few things but do them well. Somewhere I need to define how each Employee should be printed but I don't know where.

The method in **Registry** I can't get to work, I've tried:

```
public void PrintRegistry() //nr1
        {
            Accounts.ForEach(employee => Console.Write("{0}\n", employee));
        }

>            foreach(Employee employee in Accounts) // nr2
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine(employee);
>             }

Accounts.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // nr3
```

My gratitude for any help, if I need to spend a few hours to fully understand your reply I'll gladly put in the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need your own implementation of `ToString` in your `Employee` class. You just need to override it and put your code of `PrintEmployee` in the new method.

Just to make it clear what I mean I give you a sample on how the override should look like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("ID:{0}{5}Full Name: {1} {2}{5}Social Security Number: {3}{5}Wage: {4}{5}", ID, FirstName, LastName, SocialNumber, HourWage, Environment.NewLine);             
}
```

To give you a little background information: every class or struct in c# inherits from the `Object` class. Per default the `Object` class already has an implementation of `ToString`. This basic implementation would only print out namespace + class name of your Employee class. But with the above override you could simply write something like the following and get your wished output:

```
var employee = new Employee { Firstname = "Happy", Lastname = "Coder", ... }
Console.WriteLine(employee);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was missing something that simple, couldn't find the info though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution

```
private void PrintRegistry()
{
    foreach(Employee employee in Accounts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nID:{0}\nFull Name: {1} {2}\nSocial Security Number: {3}\nWage: {4}\n", employee.ID, employee.FirstName, employee.LastName, employee.SocialNumber, employee.HourWage);
    }
}
```

Or if the "PrintEmployee" PROCEDURE (not function as it doesn't return a value) is in the "Employee" class.

```
private void PrintRegistry()
{
    foreach(Employee employee in Accounts)
    {
        employee.PrintEmployee();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a procedure. It's a *method*.

Comment: I believe the definition of a "procedure" is a subroutine that does not return a value, as far as I know this is synonymous with "method"

Comment: Thanks, I will try this also

Comment: Firstly, I was talking about programming in general, secondly why?